# Get UIView height and use it for its own constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, constraints

How can I can the `height` of my `UIView` before it is actually presented?

This is what I tried:

```
print(wishWishView.frame.size.height)

self.view.addSubview(self.wishWishView)

wishWishView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
wishWishView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

wishWishConstraint =  wishWishView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor)
wishWishConstraint.isActive = true

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.transparentView.alpha = 0.7
        self.wishWishConstraint = self.wishWishView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: - self.keyboardHeight)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    }, completion: nil)
```

The problem is that `wishWishView.frame.size.height` is `0` until the view is actually presented.

What I actually want to achieve is to hide the view at the bottom. I know I could just use `constant: 1000` but that's quite brute force and not very clean.

**Edit:**

Process:

**1.** user taps on button

**2.** view appears from the bottom to right above the kayboard

**3.** user dismisses the view

**4.** view moves to the bottom out of the view

[Animation](https://gofile.io/?c=12J4CD)

I have all the `functions` and `variables` (`func viewAppears`, `keyboardHeight`,...), but I am struggling with the `constraints`.

Comment: What are you trying to do with that first constraint? You're setting wishWishView's height equal to itself.

Comment: just setting the `height`

Comment: Do you want `wishWishView` to be the same height as `self.view` ? You need to set it's height relative to another view or set it to a constant.  Equating it to itself accomplishes nothing.

Comment: oh just realized that as well.. deleted it, thanks. Do you have any idea how to solve the main problem?

Comment: @Rob I updated my question and tried something else but it's not working either

Comment: @Chris Can you post a picture of what your view should look like before and after the keyboard appearance.

Comment: @Rob sure I update the question with the animation (the appear/disappear animation right now is working, but as you can see in the video, inserting an `arrangedSubview` does not work properly

Comment: @Chris Post the code where you add the arranged subView

Comment: @Rob I did, in the other question. It is  the `priceView` . And I let it appear with `priceButtonTapped` , code is also provided in the other question

Comment: @Rob I can send you the full git project if that helps

Comment: @Chris That would be helpful. I've created a room for us to chat [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211085/ios-constraints-chris)

Comment: @Rob need you help again.. check out the chat

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you remove that last constraint, and instead, peg your view's top anchor to its superview's bottom anchor. Now you've hidden the view like you wanted.

Then when you want to unhide the view, simply change the constant of that constraint (you can use the height of your view here), and call layoutIfNeeded() in a UIView animation block.

Comment: I updated my question and tried it with your solution but couldn't make it work

Comment: Are you doing wishView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false, before you add constraints?

Comment: Also, you stored the constraint, but you're not actually changing that constraint; you're reassigning a new one. You need to modify it like this, for example, self.myConstraint.constant = 100. Then put your animation block after that.

Comment: check out my answer

Answer (score 0):

So I solved my problem and the animation is now working as expected. However the actual problem is still unsolved.

```
let height = CGFloat(130)

@objc func addWishButtonTapped(){    

    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
    self.wishWishView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: screenSize.height, width: screenSize.width, height: height)
    self.view.addSubview(self.wishWishView)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
    self.transparentView.alpha = 0.7
    self.wishWishView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: screenSize.height - self.height - self.keyboardHeight, width: screenSize.width, height: self.height)

}, completion: nil)
```

As you can see I am using the hard-coded `height`...