# Update UIView height when StackView Height is changed

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, height, uistackview

I have a `UIView` with a `StackView` inside of it and I let this `UIView` appear/disappear by a `buttonTap`.

add `UIView` with `StackView` inside of it to `ViewController`:

```
@objc func addWishButtonTapped(){

    wishView.wishNameTextField.becomeFirstResponder()

    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
    self.wishView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: screenSize.height, width: screenSize.width, height: self.wishView.height)

    self.view.addSubview(self.wishView)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.wishView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: screenSize.height - self.wishView.height - self.keyboardHeight, width: screenSize.width, height: self.wishView.height)

    }, completion: nil)
}
```

**Problem:**
Inside the StackView I want to make an `arrangedSubview` appear/disappear.

```
@objc func priceButtonTapped(){
    self.height += CGFloat(priceViewHeight)
    priceView.isHidden = false
}
```

As you can see I am using a variable `height` inside of `wishView` to track its height and use it for the animation above. The problem is that if I am calling this function to show the `arrangedSubview` but it is not updating the `frame.height` in the `ViewController`.

It is only updating the `frame.height` after I let the view disappear and appear again:

```
@objc func dismissWishView() {

    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.wishView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: screenSize.height, width: screenSize.width, height: self.wishView.height)
        self.wishView.endEditing(true)
    }, completion: nil)

}
```

This is how I setup my `WishView`:

```
//MARK: setupViews
func setupViews(){

    addSubview(theStackView)
    theStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    theStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    theStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    theStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    theStackView.addArrangedSubview(self.wishView)
    wishView.addSubview(wishNameTextField)
    wishView.addSubview(wishButton)

    wishView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70).isActive = true
    self.height += CGFloat(self.wishViewHeight)

    wishButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 45).isActive = true
    wishButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 45).isActive = true
    wishButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wishView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    wishButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wishView.centerYAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

    wishNameTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wishView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    wishNameTextField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wishView.centerYAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    wishNameTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wishButton.leadingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true

    theStackView.addArrangedSubview(self.priceView)
    priceView.addSubview(priceLabel)
    priceView.addSubview(priceTextField)

    priceView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    priceView.isHidden = true

    priceLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: priceView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    priceLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: priceView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    priceTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: priceLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    priceTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: priceView.trailingAnchor, constant: -195).isActive = true
    priceTextField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: priceView.centerYAnchor, constant: 1).isActive = true


    theStackView.addArrangedSubview(self.itemView)
    itemView.addSubview(imageButton)
    itemView.addSubview(priceButton)

    itemView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    self.height += CGFloat(self.itemViewHeight)

    imageButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
    imageButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
    imageButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    imageButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true

    priceButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
    priceButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
    priceButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    priceButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageButton.leadingAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true


}
```

I hope my problem is clear. If you need more clarification or code just let me know :)

Comment: I think more code would be helpful. You mentioned a lot different things that you didn't show code for.

Comment: If you want this to update properly I believe you're going to have to put it into a "Main" thread. Anytime you try to update the UI inside of a completion block you need to make sure that it's going to the proper thread. Your question isn't terribly clear so I could be wrong and we could really use quite a bit more code to really get a feel for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Without seeing your code it's hard to say what you want. But I have a hunch your problem would be solved if you used autolayout.

Comment: I updated my question with some more code

Comment: @Rob I tried using Auto-Layout but i couldn't get the animation working... You might have a look at my other question regarding that topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61029738/get-uiview-height-and-use-it-for-its-own-constraints

Comment: @xTwisteDx I updated the question, does this make things more clear ?

Comment: @Chris I would highly suggest that you use autolayout. I'll post a solution for you in your other post and we'll go from there.

Comment: thanks, really appreciate your help!